# Json api to set variable

Tags: json, url, channel, proc

i tries use this api with json and my output is:

> can't read "title": no such variable

,
and when i announce `$toke : <testbot> tok ::http::2`

`testid tt3896198, !id tt3896198` form imdb
url: http://api.rest7.com/v1/movie_info.php?imdb=tt3896198&title

```
bind pub "-|-" !id pub:id
proc pub:id { nick uhost hand channel arg } {
set id [lindex $arg 0]
set tok [http::geturl "http://api.rest7.com/v1/movie_info.php?imdb=$id&title"]
set data [json::json2dict [http::data $tok]]
http::cleanup $tok

dict with data
    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :$title $year $runtime $director $writer $score $genre"
}
}
```